# Swift tableview cell auto height with auto height label

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have some problems with swift.
Need to make tableview and in every cell to have image with text inside.

This is what i made so far:

[image]
[image]
**First problem:**

Label should be auto height, now it breaks string..

**Second problem:**

Image needs to be auto height too, and to depends on label height.

**Third problem:**

Row needs to be autoheight depending on its inside.

TableViewController code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
    tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
    tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "QuoteTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "QuoteCell")

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return results.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("QuoteCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! QuoteTableViewCell
    cell.item = results[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Cell code:

```
class QuoteTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var item: Quote! {
        didSet {
            setupCell()
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var imageField: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }

    func setupCell() {
        self.imageField.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "Bg")!)
        textField.text = item.text
    }

}
```

Comment: What constraints do you have on your UILabel and UIImageView?

Comment: I used constants on image view to have spacing on top and bottom, and then label constants to have spacing against that view with image.. btw i don't use imageview, i use UIView, but it is same.. i updated image where i have constants.

Comment: Did you try adding "equal heights" between the UILabel and the UI(Image)View? I think if you do that it should be fine. Also call .sizeToFit() on the UILabel after applying the text. It should better wrap the text's height then.

Comment: @TedHuinink this works, but i lost padding on top and bottom, i need little white space between rows. Solution for this?

Comment: Did you add constraints to the direct child of the UITableviewCell (in this case I think the UIView) between the top and bottom of the cell? Because it should wrap automatically when set correctly.

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly, thanks @TedHuinink :)

Comment: One more thing, how can i set min height for label?

Comment: I don't think there is such a thing in iOS. Best bet is too check if the string is empty and apply some height to the label programmatically, make sure not to call sizeToFit after that though, since it would reset whatever changes you'd make then.

Answer (score 1):

To have the label adapt its height to its contents, set its Lines number to 0 in Storyboard.

If you want to have an image next to it, why not to put both controls into one horizontal StackView?

And to have the tableView row height adapt to the cell contents (i.e. label height), just set it's rowHeight to automatic:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 90.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this metod to have that functionality

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
      let lineBrakingMode =  NSLineBreakMode.ByCharWrapping
    let paragragh:NSMutableParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragragh.lineBreakMode = lineBrakingMode
     let attributes:NSDictionary = [NSFontAttributeName: self.textField.font!, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName:paragragh]
    let TextSize = self.textField.text!.sizeWithAttributes(attributes)
    let TextHeight = TextSize.height + 5;

     UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(0.2, delay: 2.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.imageField.frame.height = TextHeight
        }, completion: nil)
    return TextHeight
}
```

}

Comment: `Use of unresolved identifier 'paragragh'` and `Value of type 'LatestViewController' has no member 'textFeild'`  - i use cell from nib