# How to set cell and label height according to text in tableview Swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview, label, height, cell

I am making chat application, here how to set label and cell height according to text coming from textfield.

**How to set initially cell height = 50, then should change height accordingly text from textfield.**

but initially i am getting small cell why?

[image]

i have given constraints for label

```
leading = 100, trailing to imageview = 10, top = 0, bottom = lessthenorequalto 0
```

for image constraint:

```
top = 20 height, width = 50 trailing = 20
```

this is the code:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ReceiverChatTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReceiverChatTableViewCell")
   tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ReceiverChatTableViewCell1", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
    //tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

Comment: same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/32984898/3501225

Comment: you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986361/swift-tableview-cell-auto-height-with-auto-height-label

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Auto Layout in UITableView for dynamic cell layouts & variable row heights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha, i have set `self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80
        self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension` but for one line text it comes small like above mentioned image.. any idea

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha, i have deleted heightforrow, edited my question, plese try to help

Answer (score 2):

when you using **UITableView.automaticDimension**, you need to set top and bottom constraints of your label. If you are set it with using **equalTo** every time cell keep that value as fixed.when your label has single line label height+(top,bottom padding) is less than your image height.thats why image crops in your case.

[image: using equalTo]

Use `lessThanOrEqualTo` instead of using `equalTo` for your label bottom constraints.

```
addSubview(lblMessage)
addSubview(img)

img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
img.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
img.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
img.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
img.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 50).isActive = true

lblMessage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
lblMessage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor,constant: 16).isActive = true
lblMessage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: img.leadingAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
lblMessage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor,constant: 16).isActive = true
lblMessage.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -16).isActive = true
```

[image]

Comment: thank u, it is working for single line text, if i enter long text then cell height is not increasing now

Comment: one mistake from me. you need to add `lessThanOrEqualToConstant` to imageview height also.i update the code.

Comment: i am giving storyboard constraints same like you.. but not getting, can i share my code using github.. its very small project.. u can solve it in minutes.. but i am fresher here

Comment: thank u, pls once check the code here, you can find in storyboard and xib cell with constraints..https://github.com/SwiftSamples/CellHeightIssue

Comment: issue is you add label and imageview to another view.so add `lessThanOrEqualToConstant` to these views instead of label and imageview